# How can I rearrange this logarithmic formula to be computer friendly?

Tags: logarithms, floating-point, computer-arithmetic

I've had a look through the [logarithmic identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities) on Wikipedia, but nothing fits the bill.

Basically, I have a formula which shows how much more 'risky' one number is compared to another, where 0 = safe and 1 = not safe for the variables `a` and `b`.

The formula is: $log_{1-b}(1 - a)$

The C# code looks like: `Math.Log(1 - a, 1 - b)` for what it's worth.

This works fine when `a` or `b` isn't an extraordinarily low number, but as soon as it becomes lower than around `1E-16`, the numbers go haywire. This is of course because double types in the computer's memory are not good at holding $1.0 - 1E-17 = 0.99999...$ <17 times>.

For example, the sum:

$log_{1 - 1E-15}(1 - 0.001) = 1.001E12$ or even:

$log_{1 - 1E-16}(1 - 0.001) = 9.01E12$ is fine, but as soon as I go an order of magnitude deeper:

$log_{1 - 1E-17}(1 - 0.001)$, I get `NaN`. This is despite that there's plenty more room in the double datatype to allow a far greater exponent for the final answer.

That's for `b` dipping below 1E-16, but a similar thing happens when `a` dips below 1E-16. But instead of NaN, I get a (wrong) answer of zero.

So I'm trying to find a way to reformulate the expression so that it's kinder to the computer. Any ideas how?

Comment: How are you computing $\log_{1-b} (1-a)$?

Comment: @copper.hat: Literally like `Math.Log(1 - a, 1 - b)` (C# code).

Comment: $\log_b(a) = \frac{\ln(a)}{\ln(b)}$ hence when $\ln b$ is too small....

Comment: @user1952009: Yes, I tried that. I still get NaN unfortunately.

Comment: when $b$ is too close from $1$, then $\ln b$ is too small, and it is clear that the result of $\log_b(a)$ will be NaN, it just means that $\log_b(a)$ is not what you really want

Comment: @user1952009: It's not that $ln(b)$ is too small, but that the computer can't hold $0.99999999999999999$ (17 nines) as a number in memory for it to calculate the log in the first place.

Comment: To first order, $\log(1+x) \approx x$ for small $x$, so you could try the approximation ${a\over b}$.

Comment: In numpy for example there is a function log1p which calculates $\ln(1+x)$ accurately even when $1+x == 1$ in the sense of floating point arithmetic. So you should be able to use log1p(-a)/log1p(-b).

Comment: @copper.hat: Good point. It's a bit of a hack though, and I think the error grows exponentially for deeper and deeper magnitudes.

Comment: @Ian: Alas the `log1p` function doesn't exist in C#.

Comment: It also exists in C++ in Math.h; you could probably transcribe that implementation into C# pretty much verbatim.

Comment: How do you want to implement this as a function? As $f(a,b) = \log_{1-b}(1-a)$? Then $b = 1-10^{-17}$ (your example) is not a issue as $b$ evaluates to $1$ for doubles when calling the function anyway.

Comment: @Winther: Exactly. I want to avoid the `1-` bit altogether if possible as that's what's causing the problem. Question is how...

Comment: An example: http://www.johndcook.com/blog/csharp_log_one_plus_x/ gives a relative error for $\ln(1+x)$ of less than $10^{-8}$, by using a two term Taylor series for $|x|<10^{-4}$ and defaulting to Math.log otherwise.

Comment: @Ian: Thinking about it, even log1p(x) wouldn't work as the number `0.999999....(17 times)` can't be stored into x in the first place.

Comment: That's not a problem, because you never use that number internally. You use $10^{-17}$, which can be accurately (but approximately) floating point represented. Note however that once 1+0.5\*x == 1, log1p(x) will be just x.

Comment: @Ian: Gotcha - sounds good. I just checked the link you provided, and it seems like an imperfect, but workable solution. I'm still curious if there's a more exact elegant answer though, but feel free to add it as an answer, and I'll at least upvote it for now. Here's [some talk](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/06/07/math-library-functions-that-seem-unnecessary/) about the issue.

Comment: This is a question that should also have been posted on CS.SE or programmers.SE, where people with more knowledge of C# or similar language families would be able to offer advice. I say this because despite the plethora of comments I've seen, no one has recommended [using the C# decimal type](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/921a8ffc-9829-4145-bdc9-a96c1ec174a5/decimal-vs-double-difference?forum=csharpgeneral), which offers much better precision than the double type. Moreover, no one's questioned you about your poorly described input range.

Comment: @Pockets: The C# Decimal type doesn't support log(). Also, yes I need higher than 10^28. But perhaps most importantly to asking here, I was curious if the expression itself could be mathematically reformulated to say the same, but without the `1-` bit. That's not a programming question any more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First we have the formula $\log_{1-b}(1-a)=\frac{\ln(1-a)}{\ln(1-b)}$. This reduces your question to computing ln(1+x) where $|x| \ll 1$.

The naive implementation can be most easily seen to fail by considering |x| less than machine epsilon. In this case 1+x==1 (in the sense of floating point ==). There is no way to make this not be the case, it is a property of floating point arithmetic that we are stuck with. So if |x| is less than machine epsilon then log(1+x)==0 in floating point arithmetic, which is a 100% relative error. Additionally, for non-representable numbers, there is still a roundoff problem even when |x| is just small but greater than machine epsilon. So the naive implementation is no good once |x| is fairly small, even when |x| is quite a bit larger than machine epsilon.

The way around this issue is to use a different function which computes $\ln(1+x)$ given x without computing 1+x. Such a function is called log1p in quite a few languages, including Matlab, C++ (Math.h) and Python (numpy).

A simple way to get similar (but *not* identical) behavior, suggested at http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/06/07/math-library-functions-that-seem-unnecessary/ is to use the usual log function for $|x|>10^{-4}$ and use a Taylor expansion otherwise. A four term Taylor expansion should be expected to nearly achieve floating point precision over this range, because the Lagrange remainder tells us that the relative error in the four term Taylor expansion carried out in exact arithmetic is less than $10^{-16}$. Note that this is a *relative* error, which is the right kind of error for your problem where you need to divide one logarithm by another.

To do better you will need to do something significantly different, because if $|x|<10^{-4}$ then $1+|x|^4$ is floating point equal to 1, so introducing a fifth term will not improve the approximation.

Comment: It looks strange that you have a paragraph starting "The issue which can't be worked around ..." and then in the very next paragraph describe a perfectly good workaround for that issue.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You're right, I phrased that poorly. Let me try to rephrase that.

Answer (score 1):

Write
$$
\log_{1-b}(1 - a) = \frac{\log(1-a)}{\log(1-b)}
$$
Many programming languages have a `log1p` function which computes $\log(1+x)$ accurately for $x$ small. If your language has `log1p`, definitely use it.